# aspectj: How to weave aspects from a library into user code?

Tags: java, eclipse, aspectj, aspect

I have a library with some classes and a few aspects in it. Say `AspectedLib.jar` is the file that contains such definitions (created in eclipse, with "export jar file with aspectj support"). If I import the `AspectedLib.jar` file, and even use some of the classes defined in it, it works, but none of the joinpoints is triggered, i.e., the aspects are not executed.

How can I make this work? Ideally, how can I set this up in eclipse*?

* Version: Juno Service Release 2; Build id: 20130225-0426

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the jar to your aspect path.  In your Eclipse project preferences, go to AspectJ build -> Aspect Path and add the jar.